# Strange colors in the application switcher (cmd+tab)

Tags: macos, finder, macbook-pro, color, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird display issue on OS X Lion when switching external monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35060/weird-display-issue-on-os-x-lion-when-switching-external-monitor)

Recently my application switcher has broken. The colors looks very odd and it doesn't help to kill finder or reboot the computer (or it works for a while after reboot..)

Image: https://img.skitch.com/20120103-pge8m1hh6eqakyy9qyjpd54x69.jpg

Is this a known issue? Where should I look to debug this issue. Is it hardware or software failure? I get this on my MBP '10

Comment: Your problem is known here. I don't know about Apple. Your question is a duplicate of [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/lion-task-switcher-icons-are-badly-discolored) and [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35060/weird-display-issue-on-os-x-lion-when-switching-external-monitor).